# alternative for Jetty Npn with OpenJdk

Tags: jetty, jvm-languages, spdy

Do you guys know of an alternative that works with Sun Jvm? We cannot use Open Jdk so I am look for an alternative NPN library that can work with Sun Jvm.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's JVM is heavily based on OpenJDK.
Have you actually tried and it did not work ?

Comment: I have not tried. Jetty `NPN` stipulates to use different `NPN` jars for different versions of  `OpenJdk`. Also the point being, we cannot use this solution as it requires replacing `ssl` implementation by placing the new jar in `boot path` (shadowing ssl implementation in rt.jar). this creates hassle for deployment and for other developers. it is nicer always if `NPN` library as be bundled in a jar with the application itself.

Comment: @Rag your question above, and your comment here are different.  Yes NPN works with Sun & Oracle JVMs and both standard and OpenJDK implementations.  Which sbordet hinted at.  However, what you want is to not use the boot classpath to use the NPN.  You will still need to use the boot classpath, but you can design your app in layers to have a bootstrap main() which forks a new JVM with the proper boot classpath you want.

Answer (score 0):

Rag, I'm actually using the official oracle jdk with the npn jar. Unfortunately it has to be in the boot classpath and there's no other way of doing it.